# Realmで初期データを作成をしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Swift 2.1
Realm 0.98

イメージとしては、クイズアプリの様に複数の質問と回答がDBに格納されて、
質問一覧から選択すると、質問文が表示され、回答を出す。

たった今Realmを導入したばかりで、全体の流れもあまり理解できておりません。

更新ドキュメントを見ましたが、モデルを作成してそこでデータに関する処理ができます。
という形でしか理解できませんでした。

イメージのものを作成する流れを教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

私は初期データ（＝シードデータ）の投入にあたっては、初回起動処理用のフラグを設けて、初回起動時にだけ流し込みを行っています。
具体的にはAppDelegateで処理をしていますので、具体的なコードをみてください（文量の関係上、一部メソッドを省略してます）。
`insertSeedData`メソッドで、kishikawa katsumiさんがご回答された準備の上で、書き込み処理を追加してください。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // 初回起動処理
        let dic = ["initialLaunch": true]
        defaults.registerDefaults(dic)
        defaults.synchronize()

        if defaults.boolForKey("initialLaunch") == true {
            print("initial setup start")
            self.initialSetUp()
        }

        return true
    }

    func initialSetUp() {
        // 初回マイグレーション
        self.realmMigration()
        // シードデータ投入
        self.insertSeedData()
        // 初回起動済みのフラグを立てる
        self.defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "initialLaunch")
        self.defaults.synchronize()
    }

    func realmMigration() {
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
            // 新しいスキーマバージョンを設定します。以前のバージョンより大きくなければなりません。
            // （スキーマバージョンを設定したことがなければ、最初は0が設定されています）
            schemaVersion: 1,

            // マイグレーション処理を記述します。古いスキーマバージョンのRealmを開こうとすると
            // 自動的にマイグレーションが実行されます。
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    // 何もする必要はありません！
                    // Realmは自動的に新しく追加されたプロパティと、削除されたプロパティを認識します。
                    // そしてディスク上のスキーマを自動的にアップデートします。
                }
        })

        // デフォルトRealmに新しい設定を適用します
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

        // Realmファイルを開こうとしたときスキーマバージョンが異なれば、
        // 自動的にマイグレーションが実行されます
        let realm = try! Realm()
    }

    func insertSeedData() {
        // realm
        let realm = try! Realm()
        // 空のアプリユーザーを作成
        let appUser = User()
        appUser.id = 1
        // 書き込み処理
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(appUser, update: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

まずデータとなる質問と回答の構造を考えます。
最低限必要なのは問題文と回答のテキストですね。アプリの性質によっては順番や難易度などが必要かもしれません。必要なデータ項目を洗い出して、それを元にクラスを設計します。

Realmではクラスがそのまま一般のデータベースでいうテーブルになります。

クラスを作るところまでできれば、実際の問題文と回答のデータをRealmに保存していきます。

これが初期データとなります。初期データの作成は適当なプロジェクトを作ってシミュレータでやるのが簡単です。

初期データの作成が完了したら、できたファイルを本当のアプリケーションのプロジェクトにコピーして組み込みます。
実際のアプリケーションでは組み込んだファイルを読み込んで使用します。

大まかな流れは上記のようになります。

現在の様子ですと、より詳しくは、Realmのチャットサポート（日本語で質問できます） http://slack.realm.io/ を使って聞かれるのが良いと思います。