# iOSアプリのアップデートでRealmマスタデータにデータを追加したい

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

アプリリリース時にはマスタデータが100件あって、
アップデートで110件に増やしたいです。

リリース時のマスタデータの挿入はこちらを参考につくりました。

[Realmで初期データを作成をしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23306/realm%E3%81%A7%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C-%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E6%96%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)

アプリをアップデートしたときにはじめてダウンロードユーザーとアップデートするユーザー2パターンいて、
アップデートするユーザーに対してどのような方法にすればスマートに処理できるのか知りたいです。

①はじめてアプリをダウンロードするユーザー(0件→110件)
insertSeedData()の中に追加したいデータを書く

②アプリをアップデートするユーザー(100件→110件)
教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: わからないところはどこですか？「はじめてアプリをダウンロードするユーザー」と「アプリをアップデートするユーザー」の区別はできていますか？それともデータをインサートする処理の書き方でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
アプリをアップデートするユーザーに対してデータを追加する処理の書き方がわかりません。
「はじめてアプリをダウンロードするユーザー」と「アプリをアップデートするユーザー」の区別ははできています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ではRealmの使い方を知りたいということでしょうか？現在は更新処理とかは使っていなくて、閲覧や初回のインサートのやり方しかわからない、ということで合ってますか？

Comment: アプリ側でダウンロードユーザーとアップデートユーザーに対してどのような切り分けでデータを挿入していくのか流れが知りたいと思いました。
表現がわかりずらくてすみません。

ダウンロードユーザーとアップデートユーザーの切り分け方がわからなかったので、　
例えば、、、　
その①　
・追加したいデータがない→追加データ挿入　
その②　
・マスタデータがあれば全部削除→追加したいデータも含めて再挿入　
のようなやり方が知りたいです。

Comment: 結局何がわからないのかがわからないです。初回インストールとアップデートの区別がつくならそれをチェックしてインサートするデータを変えればいいですし、そうでないなら一旦データを全部削除して追加データも含めてインサートでも良いです。データ量が110件程度なら速度も関係ないので好きな方でやればいいです。

Comment: 「「はじめてアプリをダウンロードするユーザー」と「アプリをアップデートするユーザー」の区別は‌​できていますか？」が、自身で理解できているのかという質問だと勘違いしていました！すみません。プログラムで区別できていないです。

Comment: それならデータを検索してみてゼロ件か100件かという条件で判断することになりますね。条件で処理を分岐して100件、または10件の追加処理を書けばいいです。おっしゃっておられるように区別せずに全部削除して110件追加するというやり方もシンプルで良いと思います。どちらがいいかは場合によります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！理解しました！
何度もやりとりしていただき感謝しています。とても助かりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントのアドバイスを参考にします。
データを検索してゼロ件か100件かという条件で判断し、条件で処理を分岐することにしました。
ありがとうございます。